# Git Merge Conflict in xCode

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5, bitbucket

I'm using (for the first time) Git as a source control of my iOS project. We are two persons working on this project. Everything was ok until the day that we modified the same file (different methods and lines).
So when I want to commit my modification xcode tell me to pull first, because my co-worker already committed his work. when I pulled I lost my local modifications.

To face this problem, what are the steps to make ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using a feature branch workflow. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows

This will allow you and your colleague to work on the same files with fairly little fuss. Share branches at your own risk!